# выборка по диапазону значений varchar и даты mySQl

Tags: mysql

доброго времени суток есть таблица catalog, mysql базы
id user date (со значениями int (ai) varchar(550) date(12) как можно организовать выборку по user и по диапазону даты

```sql
SELECT *  FROM `catalog`  WHERE user=11  AND DATE BETWEEN 2015-08-10
AND 2015-08-27
```

получаю 0 я понимаю что проблема в DATE но вот со знаниями у меня не хвататет подскажите в чем проблема для примера 2 заполненых линии 
 id    user     date
 1      11      2015-08-17
 1      11      2015-07-17
верхнию по диапазону с 16-08-2005 по 22-08-2015 и user 11

Comment: Даты в кавычки возьмите.

Comment: спасибо если хотите могу засчитать вопрос

Answer (score -1, accepted):

думаю что вы пропустили '' для даты.